# Using purrr::map with leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, purrr, r-leaflet

I'm trying to implement `purrr`'s `map()` function to add layers to a `leaflet` map, but struggling with how to reduce the result.

When I run this code, I end up with a list, where each item is a separate leaflet map (correctly generated).  Normally layers are added to leaflet maps by starting with the existing map and using the `add` functions.

I apologize for not doing a reprex, but the data is a bit too big/complex to include here.

Does anyone have suggestions for how to combine/reduce the resulting layers that end up as separate maps in a list?

```
layerlst <- lst(all_births = tibble(map = T,
                                    group = "All Births",
                                    pal = "Greens",
                                    datacol = "births_all_births"),
                birth_rate = tibble(map = T,
                                    group = "Birth Rate",
                                    pal = "Greens",
                                    datacol = "birth_rate"))

mymap <- leaflet() 


mymap <- layerlst %>% 
purrr::map(function(layer) {

palette <- colorNumeric(
  palette = layer$pal,
  domain = range(select(cdc, !!layer$datacol), na.rm = T)
)

mymap %>% 
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", group = layer$group) %>%
  addPolygons(data = cdc_geo, 
              fillColor = ~palette(cdc_geo@data %>% pull(!!layer$datacol)), 
              color = "#b2aeae", 
              fillOpacity = 0.7, 
              weight = 1, 
              smoothFactor = 0.2,
              popup = popup,
              group = layer$group) %>% 

  addLegend(pal = palette, 
            values = cdc_geo@data %>% pull(!!layer$datacol), 
            #labFormat = labelFormat(transform = function(x) 100*x, suffix = "%"),
            position = "bottomleft", 
            title = layer$group)
}
)
```

Running `mymap[1]` and `mymap[2]` to see the result correctly yield each layer.